# Make a website adaptable for iphone

Tags: java, php, iphone, http

I am owning some websites, in php, java and html coded. I want them to be viewed comfortably using iphones. ie, the site has to first check whether the site is hit from a pc or mobile (iphone). If its from a mobile, it has to be redirected to another server which loads the mobile view.
Some sites i've recently found of doing the same is orkut, facebook,etc. While logging in from a mobile, we are redirected to m.orkut.com from www.orkut.com, i've to do something similar to that.

Comment: Can you make your question a little more specific? Are you looking for guidance on how to identify mobile visitors, or are you trying to understand how to build a mobile-friendly site?

Comment: both of them, first to identify mobile visitors and then to redirect them to a mobile friendly version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the user-agent*

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

and redirect

```
header("location: http://mobile.mysite.com");
```

where necessary.

<sup>`*` Note that the iPhone has many user-agents, and therefore checking the string itself for exact comparison isn't practical. Instead, look for strings like "iPhone" and "Mobile" to determine the liklihood that the current visitor is on an iPhone.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Check the user agent. If it contains "MobileSafari" or "iPhone", its an iPhone. Other devices need a different check, of course. Google can be used to find the exact user agents, but be warned they change for each iPhone version.

PHP code to redirect:

```
header("Location: http://your-desired.site.com/");
```